# Peer2Peer CouchbaseListener

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth, couchdb, couchbase

I am working on peer to peer replication in CouchbaseLite using CouchbaseListener. I am unable to find the peers. 
Here is the code which i follow,
Note: Assue that all self. properties are available

**Here is my listener code**

```
CBLManager *cblManager = [CBLManager sharedInstance];
self.dbListener = [[CBLListener alloc] initWithManager:cblManager port:0];
[self.dbListener setBonjourName:[[UIDevice currentDevice] name]
                           type:@"_ashok._tcp."];
[self.dbListener setTXTRecordDictionary:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:DBNAME
                                                                    forKey:@"dataBasePath"]];
NSError *error;
BOOL status = [self.dbListener start:&error];
if (status) {
    dblPort = dbListener.port;
} else {
     NSLog(@"CBLListener is not started: %@", error.localizedDescription);
}
```

**started browsing the peers**

```
self.serviceBrowser = [[NSNetServiceBrowser alloc] init];
self.serviceBrowser.includesPeerToPeer = YES;
self.serviceBrowser.delegate = self;
[self.serviceBrowser searchForServicesOfType:_ashok._tcp. inDomain:@"local."];
[self.serviceBrowser scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop]
                               forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
```

But i am unable to find the peers. 
I had turn on both wifi & bluetooth on both the devices. Both are not connected to any network.

Scenarios i have tested:

1. Bluetooth & Wifi is turned on both the devices, but both are not connected to any network.
2. Bluetooth & Wifi is turned on both the devices, and both are connected to same network.

In both scenarios I am unable to find the nearby peer.

Comment: Have you implemented `netServiceBrowser:didFindService:moreComing:` delegate method?

Comment: All the NSNetService and NSNetServiceBrowser delegates are implemented.

Answer (score 0):

After crawling many forums, i've just managed to get peer 2 peer work on iOS. So i'll just post all the things that helped me (note : i call the host that has the listener running the "server" and the other one the "client" for simplicity purpose).

- First, turn on logging. You can do that by adding "-Log YES" and "-LogSyncVerbose YES" on Arguments passed on Launch (in the Edit Scheme => Run MyApp => Arguments)
- Then, you need to get the Listener service to successfully advertise itself using Bonjour. You can download iphone Apps on the app store that displays all the services available in your local network and check that the name you chose for the service can be seen.
- Then, on the "client" side you have to use NSNetServiceBrowser to browse for the service, then once the service is found use [NSNetService resolveWithTimeout] method to resolve the host. Then and only then can you build the replication using nsnsetservice hostname and port. Otherwise, those will be nil.
- Finally once you managed to connect your "client" to the "server", i suggest trying to make the replication work without any credential (no "login / password" at all) because it doesn't seem to be properly working and cause various network error, such as connexion terminating in the middle of the synchronization (even on version 1.0.2).

Hope this helped. A very useful thread to help you :
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/mobile-couchbase/p2p/mobile-couchbase/oFGn1zybDcE/7BE3vFXh9xoJ